# androidplot line not displayed

Tags: line, androidplot

I'm expecting to see a straight line defined by 2 points on my graph but nothing shows up.
I followed the tutorial and everything worked fine, then I tried to change the series of numbers. Here is the code:

plotList is of type List and it contains 2 values 12.634 and 12.634

```
    XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(plotList, 
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, 
            "Series1"); 

    // Create a formatter to use for drawing a series using
    // LineAndPointRenderer
    // and configure it from xml:
    LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter();
    series1Format.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter());
    series1Format.configure(parentActivity.getApplicationContext(),
            R.xml.line_point_formatter_with_plf1);

    //plot.setDomainRightMax(plotList.size());
    //plot.setDomainBoundaries(0, 5, BoundaryMode.AUTO);
    // plot.setDomainStepValue(1);
    //plot.setRangeBoundaries(0,40,BoundaryMode.AUTO);
    // add a new series' to the xyplot:
    plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

    // reduce the number of range labels
    plot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);
    plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelOrientation(-45);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  List<Number> plotList = new ArrayList<Number>();
   plotList.add(1212);
   plotList.add(12334);
    XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(plotList,SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series1"); 
  LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(
      Color.rgb(0, 200, 0),                   // line color
      Color.rgb(0, 100, 0),                   // point color
      Color.rgb(150, 190, 150));              // fill color (optional)

     XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);;
     plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

    // reduce the number of range labels
    plot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);
//    plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelOrientation(-45);
```

and ur xml should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        android:id="@+id/mySimpleXYPlot"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        title="Stats" />

</LinearLayout>
```